# Adding commands in the Android boot process

Tags: android, security, locking, boot, keyguard

I'm wondering if it's possible to insert my own commands in the Android boot process to modify its behavior. Specifically, I'm looking to modify the security lock where the user enters his/her PIN/password/pattern, obtain the user input, and authenticate the user myself. Upon a successful authentication, I would then like to run a few native ARM binaries before loading the home screen and sending the ACTION_USER_PRESENT broadcast.

Is this done in the framework or application level?

I've studied the Android boot process and it seems that the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent after the android system server runtime is up and running. However, this happens before the user has unlocked the device. So I'm assuming I can't do it at the system server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the most ROMs you can add the command to any file in /system/etc/init.d/ and it will be executed at boot.
Or, you can create a file in that folder, and set 755 permissions on it.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that. However, AFAIK init happens very early on in the boot process, way before the lock screen. My aim is to run the commands only after the user has successfully authenticated himself, because I don't want the commands to run until I am sure the user is who he claims to be. I can't modify the init to run the commands because of this.